# Spring-Boot with JSP project not able to run with jar or war file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, jar

I have spring boot with jsp project which can be run using main application file but when I deploy it to production with jar or war it gave me error:

> No Mapping available.

I have seen my code in debug mode it successfully read request but not able to redirect my index jsp.

**application.properties**

```
   spring.profiles.active=dev
   spring.application.name=Profiles
   server.servlet.context-path=/tagfact
   spring.mvc.view.prefix: /view/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: How are you packaging it?

Comment: this could help you.. [structuring_code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)

Comment: Can you please show some code and how your directory structure looks like

Comment: Try to use just prefix & suffix. For more review you may add your pom.xml file and configuration file (if already have).

Answer (score 1):

Follow below configuration and create structure and package as .war file and deploy to tomcat.

application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/demo-user
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

[image]